# How to make a PNG float ontop of other images

Tags: html, css, png

What css code should i use to make this transparent png element with a shadow in the png file, float over the upper image to avoid this white stripe?

http://postimg.org/image/ektu4srvn/

http://postimg.org/image/dged2yme3/

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I think OP isn't asking for anyone to code it for them or debug their code. The question wants to know which CSS rule can achieve this affect. This question can still be answered without seeing any code.

Comment: Robin you are completely right ;-) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index` CSS property to control which elements 'float' over others. An element with a `z-index` of 1 would appear above an element with `z-index` 0 when the two overlap.

[W3Schools Z-Index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

As Andy Furniss points out in the comments, in order for `z-index` to work, `position` property should be set on the element.

[W3Schools Position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Note that elements with `z-index` set need to have `position` set also.

Comment: Good point, answer updated